# Ionic2 StorageModule/Updating List

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, storage, ionic3

New to ionic and angular and I'm really enjoying it (I finally see the java in javascript!) but I'm having a problem with detecting data after it's changed.
I have a service that saves/retrieves mock data using the ionic storage module, but when I retrieve the data in my page constructor with the service, my HTML does not change.

```
    import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()
    export class IconService{

        private allNotifications:Notification[] = [];

        constructor(private storage:Storage) { 
            storage.ready().then(() => {});
        }

    public getAllNotifications(){
        this.storage.get('allNotifications').then((data)=>{
                this.allNotifications = JSON.parse(data);
        });
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            observer.next(this.allNotifications);
            observer.complete();
        });
    }    
    }
```

When I subscribe to the observable in my page, my list won't update until I interact with a button. I want the list to be updated as soon as the page is opened.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:NavParams, public modalCtrl:ModalController,
    private iconService:IconService,private storage:Storage) {
    this.iconService.getAllNotifications().subscribe(data =>this.notifications = data);
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.iconService.getAllNotifications().subscribe(data =>this.notifications = data);
  }
  }
```

However, when I call `storage.get()` from my page

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:NavParams, public modalCtrl:ModalController,
    private iconService:IconService,private storage:Storage) {
    this.storage.get('allNotifications').then((data)=>{
                this.notifications = JSON.parse(data);
        });
  }
```

the data is loaded and the html is updated as soon as the page opens. This is the html if needed:

```
<div *ngIf='notifications'>
   <button ion-fab *ngFor='let notification of notifications' [color]="day ? 'light' : 'moon'"><ion-icon name='{{notification.icon}}'></ion-icon></button>
</div>
```

I'd rather be using my service then directly interacting with Storage though, so what am I doing wrong? I've also tried not returning an observable and simply returning the parsed JSON data but that doesn't work either.

Ionic/Angular gurus, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I subscribe to the observable in my page, my list won't update
>   until I interact with a button. I want the list to be updated as soon
>   as the page is opened.

That seems to be an issue related to Angular not knowing about what you're doing in your service, so it doesn't know that it should update the view. That will also explain why the view is updated when you interact with a button.

That's because something very interesting and powerful called **Zones**. If the concept is new for you, please refer to [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html) and [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) for an amazing explanation. As you can read there,

> Application state change is caused by three things:
>
> 1) Events - User events like click, change, input, submit, …
>
> 2) XMLHttpRequests - E.g. when fetching data from a remote service
>   Timers -
>
> 3) setTimeout(),setInterval(), because JavaScript
>
> … **it turns out that these are the only cases when Angular is actually
>   interested in updating the view**.

So you would need to let Angular know that something has changed and needs to we aware of updating things. We can try by changing your code like this:

```
import { ..., NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                public navParams: NavParams, 
                public modalCtrl: ModalController,
                private iconService: IconService,
                private storage: Storage,
                private ngZone: NgZone) {

        // Subscribe only here, no need for doing it also in ionViewWillEnter
        this.iconService.getAllNotifications().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    // Now Angular knows that something has changed, 
                    // and the view needs to be checked/updated
                    this.notifications = data
                });            
            });
    }

}
```

You could also simplify the code of your service, using the `Observable.fromPromise` operator:

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class IconService {

    private allNotifications: Notification[] = [];

    constructor(private storage:Storage) { }

    public getAllNotifications(): Observable<any> {

        return Observable.fromPromise(
            this.storage.get('allNotifications').then(data => {

                // Update the data
                this.allNotifications = JSON.parse(data);

                // Return the data to the caller
                return this.allNotifications;
            })
        );
    }    
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)